# Configuring nftable firewall for one way packet traffic

Tags: linux, firewall, nftables

Hello I'm a beginner in configuring firewall, but what I want to do is to allow the host a (10.1.0.2) to send packet to host b (10.12.0.10) but that b cannot send packet to a. both machine are connected to a router. here are the command that a ran, it block traffic going from b to a but also from a to b which I don't want.

```
    nft add chain inet filter forward { type filter hook forward priority 0 \; }
    nft add rule inet filter forward ip saddr 10.12.0.10 ip daddr 10.1.0.2 drop
    nft add rule inet filter forward ip saddr 10.1.0.2 ip daddr 10.12.0.10 accept
```

Comment: What kind of traffic were you testing with, for example?

Comment: I was just using ping tool to send packet so : ping ipaddr

Comment: Right, and how did you determine that it's unable to send packets from A to B?

Comment: I opened a shell in the machine A and I ran the command : ping 10.12.0.10 and the result is : From 10.1.0.1 icmp_seq=290 Destination Port Unreachable, 100% packet loss

Comment: That doesn't mean you cannot send from A to B – it means you cannot receive the *replies* from B to A, which is exactly what you requested. Replies are packets, too. Did you intend to block all packets _including_ reply packets, or did you only want to block "new connection" packets?

Comment: Oh yes I understand now... thanks you ! I want block new connection packets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking packets from B to A also means blocking *reply* packets from B to A. Your `ping` command is able to send the Echo Request packets from A to B just fine; it just cannot receive replies, as those have been deliberately blocked.

If you want to allow bidirectional connections to be established, B must still be allowed to send packets in reply to received ones (e.g. it needs to be able to send ICMP "Echo Reply" packets, or TCP "ACK" packets, towards A).

Most commonly this is achieved by having the firewall keep state of all active connections, which is done by the "conntrack" system in both iptables and nftables.

In nftables, use the **`ct state`** rule to allow packets which belong to existing connections (i.e. replies); make sure to place it *before* the existing "drop" rule. (This would be much easier if you were editing nftables.conf and reloading it, instead of trying to insert rules one by one.)

```
table inet filter {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;

        ct state {established, related} accept
        ip saddr 10.12.0.10 ip daddr 10.1.0.2 drop
        ip saddr 10.1.0.2 ip daddr 10.12.0.10 accept
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent of iptables `--state ESTABLISHED` rules.